# Как разбить большой текст на страницы?

Tags: c#

Есть очень большой текст мне необходимо его разбить на страницы и на каждой странице выводить по 5000 символов. Как это сделать

Использую razor pages

Comment: `string[] pages = text.Chunk(5000).Select(chars => string.Concat(chars)).ToArray();`